# How to set or add a custom provider name such as linkedin, instagram in firebase login or signin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am adding LinkedIn and Instagram login to my app with the help of [linkedin-auth-example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth). This works great. But I wanted to set the provider name with the login. Any idea how to set it?
Setting the user like,

```
async function createFirebaseAccount(linkedinID, displayName, photoURL, email, accessToken) {
  // The UID we'll assign to the user.
  const uid = `linkedin:${linkedinID}`;

  // Save the access token tot he Firebase Realtime Database.
  const databaseTask = admin.database().ref(`/linkedInAccessToken/${uid}`).set(accessToken);

  // Create or update the user account.
  const userCreationTask = admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
    displayName: displayName,
    photoURL: photoURL,
    email: email,
    emailVerified: true
  }).catch((error) => {
    // If user does not exists we create it.
    if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      return admin.auth().createUser({
        uid: uid,
        displayName: displayName,
        photoURL: photoURL,
        email: email,
        emailVerified: true
      });
    }
    throw error;
  });

  // Wait for all async task to complete then generate and return a custom auth token.
  await Promise.all([userCreationTask, databaseTask]);
  // Create a Firebase custom auth token.
  const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
  console.log('Created Custom token for UID "', uid, '" Token:', token);
  return token;
}
```

I was reading about [AuthProviderConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.AuthProviderConfig) but quite not sure how to use it. Any example?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication actually only supports a few Identity Providers right now, like Google, Facebook, Twitter and GitHub, as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth).

If you would like to use any other provider as you mentioned you will need to use [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

I will attached also more reading regarding on how to setup Firebase with Instagram [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html).

I hope this helps.